# Getting ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero error

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the total volume for two quarters as the query is showing in `CASE` statements. The third CASE statement is meant to divide the total of the volume for each quarter by the total MK_VOL.

Now the issue is that the MK_VOL for each day is one value, so essentially I need to get the MAX of each day and then SUM for the whole quarter to get the MKT_SHARE (which is SUM of VOL divided by SUM of the MK_VOL). To reiterate, for MK_VOL, it's not just a case of getting the total for the whole quarter but the MAX of each day and then the total.

As you can see the MK_VOL is the same for 02-APR.

Now my third case statement is trying to do that and I get an error. This is what I need help with please or a better solution.

I have tried doing a sub query but that didn't work either.

Data Set below

```
DATE        Client   VOL    MK_VOL  
----------- -------- ----- -------          
01-APR      AB           2      45
02-APR      AC           3      46
02-APR      AG1         26      46
02-APR      AG2         48      46
03-APR      AD           4      47
06-SEP      AF           5      48
07-SEP      AF           8      50
```

Query Below

```
SELECT CLIENT
       , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-19' AND '30-SEP-19' THEN VOLUME END) AS Q3_VOLUME
       , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN '01-APR-19' AND '30-JUN-19' THEN VOLUME END) AS Q2_VOLUME
       , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-19' AND '30-SEP-19' THEN VOLUME END) AS Q3_VOLUME 
          / sum(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-19' AND '30-SEP-19' THEN MKT_VOL END) AS MKT_SHARE
FROM TB1
WHERE TRADE_DATE BETWEEN '01-APR-19' AND '30-SEP-19'
GROUP BY CLIENT
```

The expected result should be total VOL / SUM (MAX(MK_VOL) for each client.

Comment: Unfortunately your posted code doesn't run, because it contains syntax errors and also the column names don't match the names you use for the sample data. Once I corrected the query it ran without any error. So, please take the time to provide a test case which accurately reflects the code you're running and which reproduces the error you assert.

Comment: By the way, the syntax for date literals is `date '2019-07-01'`, not `'01-JUL-19'`. Luckily your current session default settings happen to make `'01-JUL-19'` work, but they won't always.

Answer (score 0):

First, your problem here is not only you could not calculate values as you wanted them to be, you had a "ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero error" error which means you had a zero value in your divisor. You have to fix it or at least you have to avoid it like i demonstrate below.

```
SELECT CLIENT
SUM(Q3_VOLUME)/SUM(CASE WHEN MKT_SHARE!=0 THEN MKT_SHARE END) V1,
SUM(Q2_VOLUME)/SUM(CASE WHEN MKT_SHARE!=0 THEN MKT_SHARE END) V2
FROM (
SELECT CLIENT,
       DATE   
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-19' AND '30-SEP-19' THEN VOLUME END) AS Q3_VOLUME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN '01-APR-19' AND '30-JUN-19' THEN VOLUME END) AS Q2_VOLUME,
       MAX(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-19' AND '30-SEP-19' THEN MKT_VOL END) AS MKT_SHARE
FROM TB1
WHERE TRADE_DATE BETWEEN '01-APR-19' AND '30-SEP-19'
GROUP BY CLIENT,DATE
)
GROUP BY CLIENT
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need max of mktvoulumes for each quarter to evaluate the ratio quarter wise. Is this what you want as below?

```
    Select
    CLIENT
   , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN 
   '01-JUL-19' AND '30-SEP-19' THEN 
       VOLUME END) ) 
    /(
     MAX(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN 
   '01-JUL-19' AND '30-SEP-19' THEN 
       MKT_VOLUME END) )  AS Q1
   , SUM(CASE WHEN DATE BETWEEN 
    '01-APR-19' AND '30-JUN-19' THEN 
    VOLUME END)
     /
    (
     MAX(DISTINCT CASE WHEN DATE 
        BETWEEN 
       '01-JUL-19' AND '30-SEP-19' THEN 
       MKT_VOLUME END) )  AS Q2
     From Table group by client
```

Comment: N. I need max of each day for the quarter and then sum of those. Thanks